# How to decode a post url string containing plus sign

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a encoded [URL string](http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/patentoutline.action?strWhere=OPD%3D%272019.02.15%27%20and%20PA%3D%27%25%E5%8D%8E%E4%B8%BA%25%27) (click to visit the page)

```
http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/patentoutline.action?strWhere=OPD%3D%272019.02.15%27+and+PA%3D%27%25%E5%8D%8E%E4%B8%BA%25%27
```

obtain by chrome inspect. I try to write a requests post function to get the page, the best I could figure out is the following, however, it does not work properly. The troubling part seems to be the plus sign. (If there is no `and` clause, `"OPD='2019.02.15'"` or `"PA='%华为%'"` works fine.)

```
import requests
url = 'http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/patentoutline.action'
params = {'strWhere': r"OPD='2019.02.15' and PA='%华为%'"} # cannot find results
# params = {'strWhere': r"OPD='2019.02.15'"} # works
# params = {'strWhere': r"PA='%华为%'"}      # works
r = requests.post(url, data=params)
print(r.content.decode())
```

Comment: so what is the problem exactly, since that returns a 200 code

Comment: are you sure you want to send a POST request ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers chrome inspect says it is a post request.

Comment: Well then... but what you have in the url is still a querystring, while what you send with `request.post` is going to be the request's body. And just following the link (as posted in your question) WILL send a GET request, of course.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I tried `requests.get(url, params={'strWhere': r"OPD='2019.02.15' and PA='%华为%'"})`, it does return correct results. The original page is obtained by POST.

Answer (score -1):

replace in the url the spaces  with `%20`

you can use a function before send it

```
str.replace(old, new[, max])
```

for example

```
params = {'strWhere': r"OPD='2019.02.15' and PA='%华为%'"} 
params['strWhere'] = params['strWhere'].replace(' ', '%20')
```